# Microsoft Word 2013: Dashed grey borders around paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Word shows me a dashed border around every paragraph which is pretty confusing.

It is definitely not a border, but rather a border that marks the dimensions of the paragraph.

It looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how to remove this dashed border?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Settings for Word, you have the option to enable or disable these lines.

Under Word. Select "File" then "Options". Under the "Advanced" tab, in the section "Show document content" you can enable or disable "Show text boundaries".

Please note, that I am using a non-english version of Word. So the precise names might not be exactly as I typed them.

If someone has access to an english Word, feel free to edit my labels to correspond to what's actually shown in the english version of Word.

Comment: You're very welcome.